# Split last tab width 50% and all other Tabs should fit in other 50% width

Tags: html, css

Need to split all tabs in such a way that. Last tab width will be 50% width and rest all tabs must fit in 50%. For now I gave fixed width: 16.65%. Would like to avoid it as there could 2 or 3 tabs excluding last tab.

Can this be achieved using `display: flex` ?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden
}

.wrapper .tab {
  float: left;
  width: 16.65%;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ccc;
}

.wrapper .last-tab {
  width: 50%;
  background: #999
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="tab">Tab 1</div>
  <div class="tab">Tab 2</div>
  <div class="tab">Tab 3</div>
  <div class="tab last-tab">Last Tab</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex; /* displays children inline */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper > .tab {
  flex: 1; /* enables growing of flex-items so they can fill flex-containers width / this is the shorthand way, but you can also use: flex: 1 1 auto; (i.e. flex-grow, flex-shrink, flex-basis) */
  /*float: left;*/
  /*width: 16.65%;*/
  text-align: center;
  background: #ccc;
}

.wrapper > .last-tab {
  /*width: 50%;*/
  flex: 0 1 50%; /* adjusted to take half of the wrappers width (i.e. initial width is set to 50%) */
  background: #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="tab">Tab 1</div>
  <div class="tab">Tab 2</div>
  <div class="tab">Tab 3</div>
  <div class="tab last-tab">Last Tab</div>
</div>
```

If you want to do it pure *flexbox* way without the use of the `width` property.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper .tab {
  width: calc(50%/3);
  text-align: center;
  background: #ccc;
}

.wrapper .last-tab {
  width: 50%;
  background: #999
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="tab">Tab 1</div>
  <div class="tab">Tab 2</div>
  <div class="tab">Tab 3</div>
  <div class="tab last-tab">Last Tab</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This work for 3 tabs. But fails for 2 tabs. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Take 2 blocks of 50-50%. Then you can easily divide inner divs as per your requirement.

Hope this helps you :)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  /*overflow: hidden*/
  display:flex;
}

.wrapper .tab-container {
  /*float: left;*/
  display:flex;
  width: 50%;
  background: #ccc;
}

.wrapper .tab {
  /*float: left;*/
  display:flex;
  width: 33.33%;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper .last-tab {
  width: 50%;
  background: #999;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="tab-container">
    <div class="tab">Tab 1</div>
    <div class="tab">Tab 2</div>
    <div class="tab">Tab 3</div>
   </div>
  <div class="last-tab">Last Tab</div>
</div>
```